# Notification does not displayed on wear, but displayed on hand held

Tags: android, notifications, wear-os

I am trying to create a notification for android device. This is the code written on the mobile. It shows the notification on the mobile phone but does not show up in **android wear**. Am I missing out on something?

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Perform action on click
            Log.i("Tag","Inside Self destruct");
            //Code for notification begins here
            PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, new Intent(context, ShowNotificationDetailActivity.class), 0);
            Resources r = getResources();
            String greetingIdText =  r.getString(R.string.notification_text);
            Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                    .setTicker(r.getString(R.string.notification_title))
                    .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_report_image)
                    .setContentTitle(r.getString(R.string.notification_title))
                    .setContentText(greetingOne.getContent())
                    .setContentIntent(pi)
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .build();
            NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(context);
            notificationManager.notify(0, notification);
        }
    });
```

Comment: is your wearable device/emulator is properly connected to your handheld device?? If you don't know, please install "Android Wear - Smartwatch" to your handheld device. And also you will need to add WEAR module into your current project and use same code for notification in WEAR module

Comment: Yes. the device is properly paired. i can see other notifications ,for eg. whatsapp,gmail.

Comment: Any errors in logcat, on either device?

Comment: I just tried your code in one of my apps and it works fine. Which tells me the problem is elsewhere (configuration, device connectivity, etc). Review the basics: uninstall/reinstall, reboot both devices, make sure Wear isn't set to block your app, that kind of thing.